# ¿como poner un scroll en un organigrama?

Tags: html5, css3

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando la pantalla se haga mas chica (responsive), el organigrama no se destruya. Quiero que conserve su tamaño y mejor que entre un scroll.

Cómo puedo hacer para que el contenido del organigrama que esta en una lista, se quede sin moverse y que el scroll pueda moverse a la izquierda y derecha, asi como las tablas responsivas?

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.page-footer a {
  margin-left: 104px;
}

.organigrama * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.organigrama ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 0px;
  /*Espacio de cuadros y lineas*/
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta2 {
  padding-top: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta3 {
  padding-top: 68px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama ul ul.lineaRecta3::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama li::before,
.organigrama li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li:only-child::before,
.organigrama li:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::before,
.organigrama li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li a {
  border: 1px solid #4A001F;
  padding: 1em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  width: 05em;
}

.organigrama li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(74, 0, 21, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  width: 05em;
}

.divContenedor {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.divContenedor .contenidoOrganigrama .listaOrganigrama {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="organigrama overflow-auto">
      <br>
      <h4 class="wow fadeInLeft">Organigrama Administrativo</h4>
      <br>
      <div>
        <h6><img src="images/iconopeq.png"> <a href="images/Organi.png" data-lightgallery="item">Organigrama Autorizado Agosto-2022</a></h6>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="contenidoOrganigrama">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="images/Organigrama/Andres.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Andres.png" alt="" width="195" height="164" /></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="images/Organigrama/Luis_rico.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Luis_rico.png" alt="" /></a>
              </li>
              <li class="lineaRecta1">
                <ul class="lineaRecta1">
                  <li>
                    <a href="images/Organigrama/Yadira.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Yadira.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="lineaRecta2">
                    <ul class="lineaRecta2">
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Alex.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Alex.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Yahaira.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Yahaira.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Belen.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Belen.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="images/Organigrama/crist.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/crist.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Emmanuel.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Emmanuel.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Irene.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Irene.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Ruben.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Ruben.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="images/Organigrama/Victor.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Victor.png" alt="" /></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Déjanos saber si alguna de las respuestas solucionó tu problema marcándola con el check y con el upvote del lado izquierdo. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para tratar de darte otras soluciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes elementos en el `CSS` que no existen en el `HTML`, como por ejemplo, no hay un `div` con clase `divContenedor`. Lo cambié por `container` que si existe, le di un ancho fijo de `1800px` y unifiqué las reglas en un solo grupo.

Con esto en mente, debes pasar las reglas de `overflow-x: auto;` y `overflow-y: hidden;` **no al** `div` que contiene al organigrama sino al `div` padre.

También eliminé la clase `overflow-auto` ya que no logré identificarla en los estilos. *Pero puedes agregarla de nuevo si la usas en otro lugar*.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.page-footer a {
  margin-left: 104px;
}

.organigrama * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.organigrama ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 5px 0px 0px;
  /*Espacio de cuadros y lineas*/
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta1:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta2 {
  padding-top: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta2:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul.lineaRecta3 {
  padding-top: 68px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama ul ul.lineaRecta3::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90px;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:first-child::before,
.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li.lineaRecta3:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama li::before,
.organigrama li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
}

.organigrama li:only-child::before,
.organigrama li:only-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.organigrama li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::before,
.organigrama li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.organigrama li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #4A001F;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.organigrama li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.organigrama ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #4A001F;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.organigrama li a {
  border: 1px solid #4A001F;
  padding: 1em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  width: 05em;
}

.organigrama li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(74, 0, 21, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.organigrama>ul>li>ul>li>a {
  width: 05em;
}

.container {
  width: 1800px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="organigrama">
      <br>
      <h4 class="wow fadeInLeft">Organigrama Administrativo</h4>
      <br>
      <div>
        <h6><img src="images/iconopeq.png"> <a href="images/Organi.png" data-lightgallery="item">Organigrama Autorizado Agosto-2022</a></h6>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="contenidoOrganigrama">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="images/Organigrama/Andres.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Andres.png" alt="" width="195" height="164" /></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="images/Organigrama/Luis_rico.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Luis_rico.png" alt="" /></a>
              </li>
              <li class="lineaRecta1">
                <ul class="lineaRecta1">
                  <li>
                    <a href="images/Organigrama/Yadira.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Yadira.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="lineaRecta2">
                    <ul class="lineaRecta2">
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Alex.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Alex.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Yahaira.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Yahaira.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Belen.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Belen.png" alt="" /></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Juan_rosales.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="lineaRecta3">
                            <ul class="lineaRecta3">
                              <li>
                                <a href="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Mariam.png" alt="" /></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="images/Organigrama/crist.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/crist.png" alt="" /></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Emmanuel.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Emmanuel.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Irene.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Irene.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="images/Organigrama/Ruben.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Ruben.png" alt="" /></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="images/Organigrama/Victor.png" data-lightgallery="item"><img src="images/Organigrama/Victor.png" alt="" /></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo disculpame que no te agradeci antes.... pero me sirvio mucho ese ejemplo que me diste.